# Uploading custom files, using CKFinder

Tags: wysiwyg

I installed CKFinder & CKEditor. They work well, and I uploaded the images. But I must give users the ability to upload pdf-s. When I try to do it through the image button uploading form, it says: "Invalid file extension.".

In /ckfinder/config.php I found this code:

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Files',              // Single quotes not allowed
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

I created the files dir under $baseDir, but it still doesn't work. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a PDF or another arbitrary file, go through the generic Link dialog:

[image]

Then use the upload form:

[image]

Comment: I was struggeling to upload mp3 file via KCFinder, I had to use 'link upload' but forgot to remember 'Simpley Sweet' solutions infront of my eys. Thanks!!